# How do I change the background color from the top of my ionic application when I reduce it?

Tags: android, ionic4

Good morning, everyone,

I have a little problem.
I would like to be able to change the color from the top of my ionic application when I reduce it....

[image: blue background color]

I don't know what this area is called either.... 
as in this screenshot. The facebook application has a blue color in the background...

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 0):

the possible solution of this query can be tricky as it also depends on the style of the launcher u using on Your phone u can try the below solutions :-

Solution 1 : -
set the statusbar color when app loads in app.component.ts

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffffff');// change the status bar color of the app so when minimize it it keeps the color u mentioned
            //rest of ur calls
});
  }
```

Solution 2:- 
Normally the minimize window takes the color of the header of the page from which the application has been reduced

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary"> <!--u can use any color or change ur color in variable.css-->
        <ion-title>Login</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately, this does not always work.

[image]

Here is the picture.
I would like the blue background to be changed to another color.
But I can't do it.